# Remove a row from a table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, html-table

I have a problem removing a row with JavaScript, since it does not have a class nor an ID, I can not reference it with CSS.

The row I'd like to eliminate begins with the text: `Post`

Hope someone can help

Comment: Can you post your code, or even better, make a demo for us on JsFiddle?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information than that. Also, your topic says "Java" which is incorrect. Another question is how do you want to remove it. Is there an Enter button somewhere? Do you click on a link? Do you have the code available of what you want to do?

Comment: Your question is extremely vague, we can't make sense of it. Also, is a jQuery solution acceptable or can you not use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does it:

```
var rows = document.getElementById('theTable').rows;

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
   if ( rows[i].firstElementChild.textContent.trim().split(' ')[0] === 'Post' ) {
       rows[i].parentNode.removeChild(rows[i]);
   }  
}
```

Note: `trim()` and what not does not work in IE8. You can leave it out, but then you have to make sure that there is no leading white-space before the word "Post".

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/xn6U8/

---

**Update:**

```
var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('basket')[0].rows;

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
   if ( rows[i].cells[0].textContent.trim().split(' ')[0] === 'Post' ) {
       rows[i].parentNode.removeChild(rows[i]);
   }  
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/A73PK/2/

Comment: This the correct way too, split(' ')[0] === 'Post' checks the beginning

Comment: hmm! I can not get it to work - here is the entire table


<table class="basket" border="0" style="width:100%;">
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr><tr>
  <td class="name">Post Danmark eller GLS takster</td><td class="price-right" align="right">0,00%</td>
  <td class="price-right" align="right">0,00 DKK</td>
 </tr><tr>
  <td>Faktura (Total m/moms)</td><td class="price-right" align="right">0,00%</td>
  <td class="price-right" align="right">0,00 DKK</td>
 </tr>
</table>

Comment: @Pete In my demo the table has an ID and I use `getElementById` to select it. Your table does not have an ID. You have to either define an ID, or use another means to select the table element. But my code works for your table. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/A73PK/

Comment: @Šime: I'd just note that `firstElementChild` and `textContent` aren't supported in IE before IE9. For `firstElementChild`, you can use `.cells[0]` instead to get the first cell in the row.

Comment: But the problem is, I can't change the Code, can't I remove the table when it has a class=

Comment: can you please help me whith the script?

Comment: @Pete You can use `getElementsByClassName`. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/A73PK/2/ This function too isn't supported in older versions of IE.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand it correctly, because "Post Danmark eller GLS takster + 0,00% + 0,00 DKK" is still Visible under result - that's what i want to remove

Comment: @Pete What browser are you using? IE?

Comment: now i see, It works in Firefox, but not ex. ie8 - can't I remove / replace it in ie8? - sorry I had not seen that you had written it earlier that it wont work in ie8

Comment: @Pete `getElementsByClassName`, `textContent`, and `trim` are not implemented in IE8. You could do without trim() if your string "Post" is right after "<td>" (without any space characters in between), and you could use `innerHTML` instead of textContent. However, you will have to implement getElementsByClassName in IE manually. Read here: http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/ Btw, you could use a JavaScript library like jQuery which supports IE8. The jQuery solution would be like so: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/A73PK/4/

Comment: wow! it works - thank you so much for your patience and help ;o)